# I am learning laravel and i want to try show a single book through a wildcard but it shows an error

Tags: php, laravel

here is my route

```
Route::get('showbooks', 'AdminController@show');
Route::get('showbooks/{book_id}', 'AdminController@singleBook');
```

here is methods for all and single book

```
public function show()
    {
        $allBooks = Book::all();
        return view ('admin.showbooks', compact('allBooks'));
    }

    public function singleBook($book_id)
    {
        $book = Book::find($book_id);
        return view ('admin.singlebook', compact('book'));
    }
```

here is link for single book

```
@foreach($allBooks as $book)
                            <h2><a href="{{ url('showbooks', $book->book_id) }}"> Book Id is: {{ $book->book_id }}</a></h2>

                            <h4>Book Title is: {{ $book->title }}</h4>
                        @endforeach
```

this is my single book view

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
                    <h1>{{ $book->book_id }}</h1>
                    <h3>{{ $book->tile }}</h3>
                </div>
```

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 655:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'books.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `books` where `books`.`id` = 1001 limit 1) this error it shows

Comment: Do you have an `id` column in your `book` table?

Comment: please help me to do it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set primary key in your model. Because by default primary key is taken as "id".

Thats why when you write

```
$book = Book::find($book_id);
```

laravel makes sql as

```
where books.id=blabla
```

Change your model as below:

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

}
```

Comment: thanks it works for me... :) i have one more question, it return result in json can i see it in simple form

Comment: I couldn't understand your ask. Please, clarify it